# How to display an image from a numpy array in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

The following short code is meant to create an array with numpy, convert it into an image object with PIL and then insert into a canvas on a tkinter window.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image

root = Tk()
array = np.ones((40,40))*150
img = Image.fromarray(array)
canvas = Canvas(root,width=300,height=300)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(20,20,anchor=NW,image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

This throws the error:

```
TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=F size=40x40 at 0x7F42D3BC3290>" doesn't exist
```

Comment: Well you are importing `*` but using `tk.`. Should probably fix that first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `PhotoImage` from `ImageTk`.

Do this instead:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

array = np.ones((40,40))*150
img =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(array))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width=300,height=300)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor="nw", image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get "TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist". Does that code work for you?

Comment: OK, the code works after adding the master=root attribute to PhotoImage.

Comment: That should not matter here. I have never used `master` with PhotoImage and this code works fine on my end.

Comment: @Mike-SMT `master=root` helps if you have multiple instances of `Tk()`.

Comment: @TheLizzard there should be no reason to have multiple instances of TK.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Debatable but it is considered bad practise. Also I left that comment for people that look at this in the future :D

Comment: @TheLizzard I would like to know what you would consider an acceptable situation to use more than one instance of Tk. Working with Tk for 3 years now and I have yet to see any reason to use more than one instance. Not being rude or anything I genuinely want to know where this would be needed.

Comment: @Mike-SMT As long as you don't need the different windows to communicate using `tkinter` variables you can use multiple instances of `Tk`. For example if I am making something like chrome, where you can drag a tab out in a new window. In that case if the user closes the master window it will close the second window as well. To stop that I will need to hide the window using `.withdraw()` but I think it would be easier to just have another instance of `Tk` for the second window. I am not sure if I explained it well.

Comment: @TheLizzard Ya that might be one. I imaging its a bit more complicated in that case but could be. The downside being that they cannot communicated so hotkeys that switch tabs probably would not work. Or other features that require communication but I can see where it might be fine.

Comment: @Mike-SMT `Alt-Tab` should still work fine. `Ctrl-Tab` never goes to the other window and the 2 windows can use normal python variables to communicate all other events. The general rule that I worked out is: if one of the windows should exist without the other (eg. a dialog window), you should use `Toplevel` otherwise you can use `Tk` or `Toplevel`. It's mostly about preference.

Answer (score 3):

`tkinter` supports only a few image formats directly, but one of them, `PPM` can be created easily from numpy data. So, here is a solution which converts an array directly to a `tk.PhotoImage` - no need to take the detour (and overhead!) of `ImageTk`:

```
import tkinter as tk

import numpy as np


def _photo_image(image: np.ndarray):
    height, width = image.shape
    data = f'P5 {width} {height} 255 '.encode() + image.astype(np.uint8).tobytes()
    return tk.PhotoImage(width=width, height=height, data=data, format='PPM')


root = tk.Tk()

array = np.ones((40, 40)) * 150
img = _photo_image(array)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor="nw", image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

The magic is in the function `_photo_image` which creates a [portable pixmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#Description) header and appends the picture data, which must be an array of bytes.

Notes:

1. the above creates a *portable graymap* (PGM). With a slight modification, this also works with color images. These have one more dimension. So, use

   ```
   height, width = image.shape[:2]
   ```

   to extract the geometry and `P6` for the *magic* value to pass in the header.

   For example, to convert an openCV image (which is usually encoded as `BGR`), use:

   ```
   import cv2

   def _photo_image(image: np.ndarray):
       height, width = image.shape[:2]
       ppm_header = f'P6 {width} {height} 255 '.encode()
       data = ppm_header + cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).tobytes()
       return tk.PhotoImage(width=width, height=height, data=data, format='PPM')
   ```
2. the above link to the [English Wikipedia page on netpbm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#Description) does not fully explain the header format (you can find it in the examples, though). The [German Wikipedia page on portable anymap](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Anymap#Kopfdaten) has more details on the header: Magic Value, space, width, space, height, space, max-pixel-value, space

Comment: Thanks Adrian for showing a direct approach from Numpy to TK, as well as the background links on portable images.  I've wondered what the byte format should be as I work with Numpy, OpenCV, and TKinter.  (I've incorporated the gray-scale approach and will add the color one soon.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, the resultant image in the canvas is mangled (lots of artifacts, lines etc and barely recognisable). The image array was generated using scikiti-mage. Another weird issue is that this only displays when in debug mode in VS Code. When in normal mode, the canvas is blank. I've confirmed that the data is good, because the same numpy array displayed in matplotlib looks fine. Could this be a data formatting issue?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help much on this. The technique shown is being heavily used in a project of mine since many years and just works. I'm unsure what you might mean with "data formatting". The dimensions of the array must match the picture format, of course, See the differences between the two examples above. So, if you might have a monochrome image, don't try to convert colors. I have used 8-bit pictures, but it should also be possible to extend the resolution to 16 bit by specifying `65535` instead of `255` for the max. data value. Quite some possibilities of doing something wrong...